# Making a select option stay selected. Cookies?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a very simple select option, I'm hoping for it to trigger a refresh and specific action when clicked. But before I get to that I want to know how I can keep it selected after any refresh or action.

```
<select name="countries" id="countries" style="width:180px;">
<option value='us'>United States</option>
<option value='gb'>United Kingdom</option>
</select>
```

Any ideas, I've looked into cookies, but would appreciate some help with it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include jquery.cookies.js

http://code.google.com/p/cookies/wiki/Documentation

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function change_action(selected_value)
    {
       $.removeCookie("test");
       $.cookie("test", selected_value);
       //make select box selected by placing a id

       //Even this line is not necessary now
       //$('#'+selected_value).attr('selected', true);

       //Provide the URL needs to be redirected
       window.location.href = '';
    }
    </script>
```

Following is the html code,

```
//In php check whether cookie is working
   <?php
   echo $_cookie('test');
   ?>
    <select name="countries" id="countries" style="width:180px;" onchange="return change_action(this.value);">
        <option value='us' id="us" <?php if($_cookie('test') == 'us') { ?> ?>selected='selected'<?php } ?>>United States</option>
        <option value='gb' id="gb" <?php if($_cookie('test') == 'gb') { ?> ?>selected='selected'<?php } ?>>United Kingdom</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: I think my main issue with all these cookie options i've tried, is that I'm not including the code properly, I've uploaded an example of your code on this link - http://jermainecraig.co.uk/country/ ... Is this set up correctly, because it's still not working for me.

Comment: @user3272400 and check by giving alert inside your javascript.

Comment: I've done this, but the page is not returning anything, do you know what this means?

Comment: Then its a php error. use error_reporting(E_ALL) and find the error and fix it.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but I'm not to great with programming yet, and really have no idea how to do that. I believe the Cookie test echo is the issue. Once removing that the select is showing again.

Comment: I did a mistake in hurry. $_cookie['test']

Answer (score 0):

Check This, Done in Jquery , Have some code which u may not need , This was done for some other question just modified for ur option

```
  $(document).ready(function(e){
     var name = "Country=";
     var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
     for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++)
  {
  var c = ca[i].trim();
  if (c.indexOf(name)==0) $('#countries').val(c.substring(name.length,c.length));
  }
});

$('#countries').change(function(e)
{
    var cookieVal = "Country="+$(this).val();
document.cookie = cookieVal ;

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AmarnathRShenoy/HM3Zj/2/

Comment: So shouldn't the selector on this link work? http://jermainecraig.co.uk/country-two/

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="countries" id="countries" style="width:180px;" onchange="change_language(this.value)">
<option value='us' id='us'>United States</option>
<option value='gb' id='gb'>United Kingdom</option>
</select>

<script>
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays)
{
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
}




function getCookie(cname)
{
var name = cname + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) 
  {
  var c = ca[i].trim();
  if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
  }
return "";
}


function change_language(lang)
{
setCookie("flag_option_dropdown",current_flag,30);
var flag_current_option_dropdown=getCookie("flag_option_dropdown");
document.getElementById(flag_current_option_dropdown).setAttribute("selected","selected");
}

change_language("gb"); //by default




<script>
```

You may working on language translator, i have solved this problem in this way. best of luck

Comment: There is typo in the JS-code: `lang` is passed into `change_language`, though the function uses `current_flag`...